# Mapbox GL JS .setData() loop performance optimization

Tags: optimization, mapbox-gl-js, web-optimization

[image]
[image]
[image]
Every 50 milliseconds, I am receiving an update from a server and then I am updating the point data in my Mapbox GL JS like this:

```
    map
      .getSource('pointsSource')
      .setData(pointsData);
```

The drama begins when I discover that my laptop goes in turbo mode and uses 200% of the CPU, whereas where I am not doing `.setData()` (not updating the data but only displaying the map) it works using **25%.**

At any given time, I am updating only 25 points. How can I improve performance considering that it is not related to the number of points but rather to the fact that I am calling `.setData()` very fast? I think this way because I did experiments with **1** point or **10000** and the result is the same **(200% CPU).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `setData` is intended to be called so frequently. If you don't need to move the geometry (just attributes) you might be able to use `setFeatureState` instead.

Alternatively, at least to stop the window locking up, you could wait for the `idle` event before calling `setData()`:

`map.on('idle', () => map.setData(...));`

Comment: can you elaborate on 'wait for the idle event' statement

Comment: Added a code example.